# How to Restrict Users to Sign as per date difference in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on one requirement where I have to show / hide Sign tag as per
the number of days calculation.

I tried to use two datafield for "Date"  date type:

*DateSigned* = "11/05/2015"
*DateReceived*= "11/01/2015"

Added one more Datafield NumberofDays  "number" type and added initial
value 14 days.

So , I want to calculate difference b/w to dates and if this difference is
greater than 14 days, I need to show Sign tag on documents else I need to
hide it.

I tried to use formula on template but it seems, not working

*Formula is used = DateDiff([DateSigned], [DateReceived]) >
([NumberofDays])*

I can always see Signature tag visible whether I update any value in
NumberofDays.

Is there any otherway like if we can open Recipient[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u6vC.jpg)/Signer view using Iframe and Iframe can be made read only.

your help is really appreciable.Attached image for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the DocuSign conditional tab logic does not support greater than or less than operators. It only supports "equals specific value" or "not blank".

A crude workaround using the conditional logic tabs support: lets say i want a signature tab to appear if a delta is 1,2, or 3. I would create THREE unique signature tabs, each with specific conditional logic to appear if the delta/calculated value is 1, 2, or 3.  If i needed to support 5 unique values, then that would result in 5 unique signature tabs. Granted, only ONE would actually be visible/appear based on the end calculation.

Comment: Thanks, Luis. I have achieved this while using custom tag and formula tags. My whole purpose was to restrict user to sign as per the Document Sent Date and current day.                                                                      Can we hide finish button if user has not signed document and Sign here tag is also hidden as per the logic.                                             What is happening right now ; I am able to hide / show Sign here tag but still Finish button displays ;so user still can click on Finish button and document status updates from InProcess to Completed.